# How to remove the default 'Are you sure' popup when navigating from a page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have tried the below mentioned code to generate a popup when the user tries to navigate away from the current page.This pop-Up appears but as soon as user clicks OK or Cancel ,the default  pop-Up appears as- "Are You Sure" pop-Up("This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.").

```
 var msg = "Mandatory fields left unsaved!!!";
    // open hidden layer
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return confirm(msg);
    }
```

I do not want the default popup to appear.Is it possible?
If not,how can i modify the message which is being displayed on default pop-Up.

Comment: You can try a jQuery model dialog - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="Default.aspx" onclick="return check()" id="link">Click ME</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var msg = "Mandatory fields left unsaved!!!";
    function check() {
        return confirm(msg);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `onbeforeunload` is set for window.use :

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Comment: But this would disable both the pop-Ups.I want that only default pop-Up should not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browser your user(s) are visiting your page(s) with, they may not actually see your custom message: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

In a nutshell, while the method allows a return value, the [browser is not required to use it in the prompt](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/history.html#unloading-documents). This (ignoring the text value) is the behavior I've seen in browsers I test against when trying to do roughly the same as your example.